# forall statmant doesn't work - no data found

Tags: oracle, plsql

keep getting

> "element in index [1] does not exist"...

but I do get output from the `"dbms_output.put_line (v_lahad_wiz_eq.count);"`, about 20 lines of '`100`' and then a line of '`61`' and a '`0`', so there is data getting in...

```
declare 
c_limit number :=100;
--set data type and set verible
type lahad_wiz_eq_typ is table of  lahad_wiz_eq%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;                                    
v_lahad_wiz_eq                                lahad_wiz_eq_typ;

cursor c1 is 
   select *  
   FROM wiz_equip_trx q
   WHERE q.ACCOUNT_NUMBER > 0
   AND q.MANUFACTURER = 'FK';

begin 

open c1 ;
loop 
 fetch c1 
 bulk collect into  v_lahad_wiz_eq
 limit c_limit;
 dbms_output.put_line (v_lahad_wiz_eq.count);
 exit when v_lahad_wiz_eq.count = 0;
end loop;      
close c1; 

dbms_output.put_line (v_lahad_wiz_eq.last);

forall i in 1  ..  100
   insert into lahad_wiz_eq 
   values v_lahad_wiz_eq (i) ;  
dbms_output.put_line ( sql%rowcount);

commit;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not loop to get records through `BULK COLLECT` as you do for normal `FETCH INTO`statements and hence no  need of `EXIT WHEN`. Actually, Your loop was overwriting the collection the second time with no values and `exit when v_lahad_wiz_eq.count = 0` satisfied the second time to come out of loop.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
    c_limit          NUMBER := 100;
--set data type and set verible
    TYPE lahad_wiz_eq_typ IS
        TABLE OF lahad_wiz_eq%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
    v_lahad_wiz_eq   lahad_wiz_eq_typ;
    CURSOR c1 IS SELECT
        *
           FROM
        wiz_equip_trx q
                 WHERE
        q.account_number > 0
        AND   q.manufacturer = 'FK';

BEGIN
    OPEN c1;

    FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO v_lahad_wiz_eq LIMIT c_limit;
     dbms_output.put_line (v_lahad_wiz_eq.count);
    CLOSE c1;

    dbms_output.put_line(v_lahad_wiz_eq.last);

    FORALL i IN 1..v_lahad_wiz_eq.COUNT
        INSERT INTO lahad_wiz_eq VALUES v_lahad_wiz_eq ( i );

    dbms_output.put_line(SQL%rowcount);
    COMMIT;
END;

/
```